# BigCommerce Stencil - Product Variant Stock Levels

Tags: json, bigcommerce

A client wants to set up A/B testing on the Product Detail Page related to the `stock_level` of a product's variants. Once the user selects their options, if the quantity is less than 5, I'd show something like "Hurry, only 3 more in stock"...

I believe I have the correct Inventory settings enabled, because I can retrieve the `stock_level` of a product without options.

Has anyone had success pulling variant SKU stock_levels in stencil?

Thanks

Comment: This is on the product page?

Comment: Correct. Just edited to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using javascript in the `assets/js/theme/common/product-details.js` file. On initial page load and each time a product option is changed, there is a function `updateView(data)` that is called. The `data` parameter contains all the info you need for the selected variation.

Starting on line 285, replace this:

```
updateView(data) {
    const viewModel = this.getViewModel(this.$scope);

    this.showMessageBox(data.stock_message || data.purchasing_message);
```

with this:

```
updateView(data) {
    const viewModel = this.getViewModel(this.$scope);

    if(data.stock < "5") {
        data.stock_message = "Hurry, only " + data.stock + " left!";
    }
    this.showMessageBox(data.stock_message || data.purchasing_message);
```

Comment: I'm running an early beta version of Stencil, so this function is called productOptionsChanged(), but the data is there and has everything I need. Awesome answer, thanks!